# power4gear for Linux alternative

Tags: windows, 16.04

I have switched to Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed all drivers. I am using an Asus laptop (n56vz). In order to use its maximum power, I had to install and use Power4gear when I was running Windows.

I would like to know if there is any alternative software which is working like Power4gear but for Linux. Alternatively, is there any way to boost/force my laptop to use all its capabilities?

Right now, when I open 5-6 YouTube videos it starts lagging.

My specs are:

- 2 GB 650gt mobile
- 16 GB RAM
- core-i7
- 512 SSD

Comment: Thank you for editing but is there anyone who can help me ? I already checked few apps for Ubuntu which were able to help me for CPU performance control like Jupiter and Cpufreq but both of them are now supported/working anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linux world offers less 'pseudo optimization tools' from my point of view

What you might consider is - and that doesn't covers everything for sure:

**TLP regarding battery usage**

TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to fulfill your specific requirements.

You can install TLP via

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

So tlp will most likely not boost your power (however you might define that) - but help optimize battery usage.

**GFX Driver regarding graphic power**

Ubuntu comes with a GUI which lets you choose 'Additional drivers'. Usually this covers primarily the graphic drivers - check what you are currently using and consider testing others.

[image]

It really depends what hardware you are using here - feel free to add this info to your initial post.

**Regarding flash**

Flash support on Linux isn't perfect - to be honest the best working solution i know for that area is using Google Chrome with its in-build flash version and in addition try to prefer HTML5 on Youtube instead of flash itself to reduce the amount of flash usage in general.

Answer (score 1):

CPU control is done via inbuilt intel_pstate thats in the kernel. This effectively controls the CPU power as per need basis. Apart from that TLP as suggested above will help you optimize your system as per the power source. In battery mode it goes on saving mode and turns off turbo on CPU. In power mode all power saving optimizations are turned off. Power4Gear basically would run the CPU at full frequency under Windows. No need for that as Intel's own pstate takes care of that well.